# What is the difference between max() and maximum() in Julia?

Tags: julia, max, built-in

I am currently learning about the built-in functions in Julia, specifically `max` and `maximum`, and I am seeking clarification on their differences.

```
julia> max(1, 2, 3, 4)
4
julia> maximum([1, 2, 3, 4])
4

help?> max
search: max maximum maximum! maxintfloat argmax typemax findmax findmax! Cintmax_t floatmax Cuintmax_t Matrix minmax BitMatrix macroexpand @macroexpand

  max(x, y, ...)


  Return the maximum of the arguments (with respect to isless). See also the maximum function to take the maximum element from a collection.

  Examples
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  julia> max(2, 5, 1)
  5
```

I see no difference between these two functions. It seems that `maximum()` has more functionality than `max()` and can do all thing `max()` do.

Why do they separate into 2 difference function? Why both exist together? Can you give me some examples where these two functions work in different contexts?

Comment: You say you see no difference then describe how `maximum` has more functionality.  It cannot be both different and identical.

Comment: Perhaps you are intended that you do not understand why both need to exist?

Answer (score 5):

The documentation you included in your post makes it clear:

> See also the maximum function to take the maximum element from a collection.

`max()` operates on a list of independent arguments, while `maximum()` operates on a single argument that is a *collection*.

In your trivial and unrealistic example of course it makes no difference because you created the collection from literal values as a temporary instance from literal values.  In a more realistic application, you would use whatever suited the input you were processing, which may or may not be a collection.  While you could instantiate a temporary collection from independent variables in the same way, it would be an unnecessary processing overhead.

In your examples with only literal values, the use of one over the other is perhaps not clear.  But it is an unrealistic example.  If you had a number of independent variables, it would be inefficient to collate them into a collection only to determine the maximum.

```
x = 0
y = 10
z = 5
max( x, y, z )      # maximum of x, y, z
maximum( [x,y,z] )  # Create a temporary collection from x,y,x and return maximum

a = [x,y,z]
maximum( a )        # Maximum of an existing collection
max( a )            # ERROR: a is not a collection.
```

Interactively at https://julialang.org/learning/tryjulia/:

```
julia> x=1
1

julia> y=3
3

julia> z=2
2

julia> a=[x,y,z]
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 3
 2

julia> maximum(a)
3

julia> max(a)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching max(::Vector{Int64})
Closest candidates are:
  max(::Any, ::Missing) at missing.jl:130
  max(::Any, ::Any) at operators.jl:419
  max(::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any...) at operators.jl:560
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[6]:1

julia> max(x,y,z)
3

julia> ^C

julia>
```

So you use the function appropriate to the data type you have, and the data type you have depends on what you are doing in the wider context of a larger program.  If processing a lot of data iteratively or for data that is "collected" at run-time and which may be added to or removed from over time, you are unlikely to be using independent variables.

Comment: Can you provide more realistic application of both function? It's really helpful to me to find the key difference between them.

Comment: To be honest I had never heard of julia before your question, and have never seen any julia code.  I can however read and understand the documentation and am familiar with several other languages and know how computers work.  So I am not the best person to ask.  You would however choose the function that worked with the data types you have.  It would be inefficient to collate multiple separate values into a _collection_ simply to use `maximum()` instead of `max()`.  It becomes an issue when you are working with _variables_.  Your examples with literal values are not very realistic.

Answer (score 2):

As Clifford has already pointed out, `maximum` operates on collections and the sizes of collections are in general not known at compile time. That being said, it is possible to use `max` with collections as well by using `...`, but per my understanding it is not recommended for any collection whose size is not statically known.

NB I am not a compilers guy, especially not a Julia compiler guy. So, I do not know what exactly happens in the different cases. This is just intended to make the point that `max` and `maximum` should not be used interchangeably.

```
julia> xs = rand(10)
10-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.34747000762279256
 0.00868217104832747
 0.13218902452742898
 0.8467868702183277
 0.27549007470760745
 0.12099609627549013
 0.6724461023554089
 0.6493350852320885
 0.6318376513505265
 0.7677036329934219

julia> maximum(xs)
0.8467868702183277

julia> max(xs...)
0.8467868702183277
```

`maximum` does a loop over the collection, obviously. Understanding what `max` does, at least from the perspective of native code, requires some understanding of calling conventions (e.g. how arguments are passed to functions). `max` operates on values passed in registers and via the stack, i.e. it requires the number of items to be known at compile-time. `maximum` on the other hand operates on some heap-alloc'd data.

In general, the sizes of collections are not known at compile-time, so using `max` like this in some generic code that is not in the REPL will most likely result in type type instability, and hence severe slowdowns.

```
julia> xs = rand(1000);

julia> @code_native max(xs...)
... 
    vmovups %ymm0, 7304(%rax)
    vmovups 7312(%rbp), %ymm0  # move value in stack to register ymm0
    vmovups %ymm0, 7336(%rax)  # move from register ymm0 to some other address
    vmovups 7344(%rbp), %ymm0  # repeat for all arguments...
    vmovups %ymm0, 7368(%rax)
    vmovups 7376(%rbp), %ymm0
    vmovups %ymm0, 7400(%rax)
    vmovups 7408(%rbp), %ymm0
    vmovups %ymm0, 7432(%rax)
    vmovups 7440(%rbp), %ymm0
    vmovups %ymm0, 7464(%rax)
    vmovups 7472(%rbp), %ymm0
    vmovups %ymm0, 7496(%rax)
    vmovups 7504(%rbp), %ymm0
    vmovups %ymm0, 7528(%rax)
    vmovups 7536(%rbp), %ymm0
    vmovups %ymm0, 7560(%rax)
    vmovups 7568(%rbp), %ymm0
    vmovups %ymm0, 7592(%rax)
    vmovups 7600(%rbp), %ymm0
    vmovups %ymm0, 7624(%rax)
    vmovups 7632(%rbp), %ymm0
    vmovups %ymm0, 7656(%rax)
    vmovups 7664(%rbp), %ymm0
    vmovups %ymm0, 7688(%rax)
    vmovups 7696(%rbp), %ymm0
    vmovups %ymm0, 7720(%rax)
    vmovups 7728(%rbp), %ymm0
    vmovups %ymm0, 7752(%rax)
...
    vmovups %ymm0, 7912(%rax)
    vmovups 7920(%rbp), %ymm0
    vmovups %ymm0, 7944(%rax)
    movq    %rax, 80(%rsp)
    movabsq $139643313038512, %rcx          # imm = 0x7F013E11A4B0
    movq    %rcx, 96(%rsp)
    movabsq $139643322340352, %rcx          # imm = 0x7F013E9F9400
    movq    %rcx, 104(%rsp)
    movq    %r15, 112(%rsp)
    movq    %rax, 120(%rsp)
    movabsq $jl_f__apply_iterate, %rax
    leaq    96(%rsp), %rsi
    xorl    %edi, %edi
    movl    $4, %edx
    vzeroupper
    callq   *%rax
...
```

By the looks of it, this is what is happening -- the entire array "gets copied to the stack" (address offset from `%rbp` register, quotes because this happens at compile time, sort of) , then again gets copied to some location in memory (pointer stored in `%rax` plus some offset). Consider the following benchmarks.

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime max(xs...)
  52.051 μs (2003 allocations: 55.00 KiB)
0.9999736504713679

julia> @btime max($(xs...))
  2.017 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
0.2307205152110382

julia> @btime maximum(xs)
  849.239 ns (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
0.9999736504713679
```

In the general case, you will be hitting the first benchmark time because collections sizes are not known at compile time.

Finally, consider the following benchmarks.

```
julia> x1, x2, x3, x4, x5 = (1,2,3,4,5)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

julia> xs = [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5];

julia> @btime maximum($(xs))
  7.746 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
5

julia> @btime max($(x1), $(x2), $(x3), $(x4), $(x5))
  3.893 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
5
```

Long story short: use `max` when the number of arguments is small and known at compile time, use `maximum` for heap allocated collections. Both have their intended purposes.

### Edit: when is it okay to use `max(xs...)`?

When `xs` is a something like a `Tuple`, or perhaps even `StaticArray`, because the number of elements is known at compile time.

Comment: It'a pitty that a implementation issue scaled up into the user API...

Comment: I don't think that's the reason, @Antonello. I believe `max` and `maximum` were seen as semantically different functions. See e.g.
 https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/11872

Answer (score 1):

`maximum` accepts a function argument:

```
julia> maximum(length, ["Julion", "Julia", "Jule"])
6
```

`max` uses `isless()`.